# SWF to PDF batch convert

Tags: flash

I have hundreds of files in swf format (it's an ebook), I want to batch covert them into pdf (to read them on my iPad).

I tried few like **eConverter** (didn't work get error with swfdec), also this may not do the batch coversion.

**swftool**, worked well, but very poor quality. I can't read the letters.

**SWF Printer** Pro again poor quality

**ffmpeg** gave error "Compressed SWF format not supported"

It'll be great if you guys help me out to find a solution. thanks

Comment: Nowadays there is also reaConverter

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read them on iPad, you can do:

1. Create an ORB book in Finder.

Package all of your swf files to one .orb file. (one swf per page)

http://rintarou.dyndns.org/2014/09/13/create-an-orb-book-in-finder/

2. Download ORB Viewer for iPad (Lite is free with Ads and only open the first .orb file).

Use it to read the .orb file on iPad.

http://rintarou.dyndns.org/works/orb-viewer/

If you really need to convert them to PDF, you can purchase ORB Reader for Mac.

It'll read .orb on Mac and also convert to PDF.

PS. I am the author of these apps mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with a HotKey script. A sample (with explanations and link to the HotKeyNet script-host software) is appended below. (Note: This answer is specific to Windows platforms.)

```
// Software: http://hotkeynet.com
// http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html
// https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/

// Script for HotKeyNet (0.1.45 Build 210) to automate
// converting many .SWF files to PDFs by opening each SWF in
// Adobe's standalone Flash Player and then printing it as a
// PDF file using Foxit Reader's virtual PDF printer. The SWF
// files' contents are static (not animated), and are thus
// suitable for printing. They are pages of a print magazine
// and the files contain multiple objects - images, text,
// fonts, and rendering and layout information.

// The script works by sending a sequence of keystrokes
// to the main and child windows of Adobe Flash Player
// and Foxit Reader's PDF Printer

// To use this script:
// 1) Load it in HotKeyNet.exe, then:
// 2) Minimise HotKeyNet to the taskbar.
// 3) Set Foxit's PDF Printer as the default printer.
// 4) Open file 01.swf in Adobe Flash Player, and manually
//    perform the above sequence for converting it to PDF
//    to establish the source and destination folders to
//    be used by the player and the virtual printer.
// 5) Ensure that the flash player has the focus. (i.e.
//    that it is the foreground application.)
// 6) Press the HotKey defined below to run the script.


// Part 1: Define a user-command "PrintOnePage".
// Within the command, %1% stands for a parameter
// passed to the command, which will be a filename.
// That name will be used as both the .SWF file to
// be opened and the .PDF file to be written.

<Command PrintOnePage>
        <sendpc local>
            <sendwin "Adobe Flash Player 23">

// Key sequence to open a file in the player:
// Alt+F, O, Alt+B, filename, Alt+O, Enter 

            <key LAlt F>
            <key O>
            <key LAlt B>
            <wait 500>
            <text %1%>
            <key LAlt O>
            <wait 500>
            <key Enter>

            <sendwin "Adobe Flash Player 23">

// Key sequence to print the file as a PDF:
// Alt+F, P, Alt+P, Alt+N, filename, Enter

            <key LAlt F>
            <key P>
            <wait 4000>
            <sendwin Print>
            <key LAlt P>
            <wait 500>
            <sendwin "Print to PDF Document - Foxit Reader PDF Printer">
            <key LAlt N>
            <text %1%>
            <key Enter>
            <wait 12000>

// End of user-command definition


// Part 2: Define a HotKey that, when pressed (once),
// will run the above command multiple times with a
// different parameter each time. They are 02, 03, 04,
// etc, which are the SWF and PDF filename pairs.

<hotkey F1>
<PrintOnePage 02>
<PrintOnePage 03>
<PrintOnePage 04>
<PrintOnePage 05>
<PrintOnePage 06>

// Add a line for each page file

// End of script
```

Comment: Please consider adding some essential details from the link. The link might become invalid later; in that case, people will still be able to benefit from your answer.